# creating an rpm package to install httpd,php,python3 and configure them by replacing configuration files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating an rpm in which httpd,php,python3 should be installed in centos 7.

```
Name: test
Version: 1 
Release: 0
Summary: Securaa RPM Creates specific files 
Group: Applications/test
License: GPL
Source0: test-1.tar.gz
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-buildroot 

%description
Creates YUM repository pointing local network CentOS repository

%prep
%setup -q

%install
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
cp -R * "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"

%clean
rm -rf "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"

%post
echo ..

echo "Executing script"
/etc/test/test.sh

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/etc/test/test.sh
```

In `test.sh`:

```
yum install httpd
yum install php 
yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
```

rpm is built and after executing rpm the necessary packages are not getting installed.

Comment: test.sh is not getting executed after running rpm

Answer (score 2):

If your custom package requires other packages as dependencies, then use `Requires` in your spec file to list these; don't try to install them via a shell script.

For example, for your package:

```
Requires: httpd php python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
```

Further details here: https://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html

Comment: will there be an issue if i do it in shell script

Comment: My understanding of Linux packages is that when packages are installed, a lock is placed on the RPM database (by `rpm` or `yum`).  That lock is released when the package is fully installed.  You're trying to install further packages via a shell script in the middle of that process, which would require a further lock to be placed on the database (whilst one is already there).  I don't think that's allowed, hence why you need to use the `Requires` keyword.